# Exact match word from text file and print line containing word

Tags: python, python-3.x

Text file:

```
InheritedFrom: abc@aol.com

InheritedAltFrom:  abc@aol.com

From:  CN=deepak sethi/O=MHI

INetFrom:  xwy.com
```

code I am using to extract line containing "From:" only

```
import re

with open('abc.txt', 'r') as file:
         raw = file.readlines()

for line in raw :  
    if  re.search(r'/b' + "From:" + r'/b', line):              
        print (line)
```

expecting :-

`From: CN=deepak sethi/O=MHI`

I dont understand what's going wrong?

Comment: whats your output?? @NipunKhanna

Comment: Can't you do that with the terminal command 'grep' ? If it is a very big file, that is probably faster than Python it is automatically multi-core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

with open('abc.txt', 'r') as file:
     raw = file.readlines()

for line in raw :
    if re.search(r'^From:', line):
        print line
```

Will solve your problem

Comment: Can we do re.search from a list of string with a file.

Answer (score 2):

Regexp's *word boundary* is presented with `\b`, not `/b`:

```
with open('abc.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        if re.search(r'\bFrom\b', l):
            print(l)
```

The output:

```
From: CN=deepak sethi/O=MHI
```

Comment: while this matches the word boundary, what if we wanted to search `From:`, how would it be? Supposing the string did not start with `From:`

Comment: I think it matters as it would not match `From:`, because it contains `:`.

Comment: @user3764893, colon `:` is already a word boundary, so use `\bFrom:`, that's all

Comment: you are right about that. What confuses me is that `re.search(r'\bFrom:\b', l):` would not match, while `re.search(r'\bFrom:', l):` matches. What is the reason behind this?